# How to make axios show full pages when sending to firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, axios

Ran into some issues when using Axios and any help would be much appreciated.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { async } from '@firebase/util'
import { initializeApp } from '@firebase/app';
import { get, getDatabase, ref, child, set } from 'firebase/database'

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "REAPALCED",
    authDomain: "REAPALCED-REAPALCED.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://REAPALCED-4fbb2-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "REAPALCED-4fbb2",
    storageBucket: "REAPALCED-4fbb2.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "REAPALCED",
    appId: "REAPALCED",
    measurementId: "G-REAPALCED"
  };
  
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


const communityUrl = 'https://www.REPLACEDURL.com/';
const apiKey = 'REPLACEDAPIKEY';
const endpoint = '/nexus/purchases';

axios.get(communityUrl+'api'+endpoint+'?key='+apiKey).then(resp => {
  const db = getDatabase()
  const dbRef = ref(getDatabase())
 // console.log(resp.data)
 const test = resp.data.results

  set(ref(db, 'hello5'), resp.data.results)

})
```

As you can see I tried using `.results` as it pulls everything but for me, it doesn't pull all the results I have (around 500) it caps to 24 results.

Comment: I added REAPALCED to the fields that were sensitive.

Comment: This does not seem like a problem with Axios but with the server. Do you receive 500 objets in the network explorer?